# Cannot set text to EditText from custom dialog

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, android-alertdialog, android-textinputedittext

I had some problem with setting text to EditText. There are no error occur and I can get text from customDialog, but when I set text to edittext nothing happen.

This is a pact of xml file that use to set up edittext.

```
<LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/setting_layout_fname"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="100"
            android:clickable="true">

            <TextView
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="25"
                android:clickable="false"
                android:text="Firstname"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" />


            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/setting_textLayout_fname"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:layout_weight="75"
                android:clickable="false">

                <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                    android:id="@+id/setting_edittext_fname"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:clickable="false"/>
            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
```

And this is code to handle my alertdialog.

```
package com.example.yggdrasil.realapplication;

import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class setting extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

private android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar toolbar;
private LinearLayout linear_fname, linear_lname, linear_birthdate, linear_gender, linear_tel,
        linear_carefname, linear_carelname, linear_careemail, linear_caretel, linear_range,
        linear_min, linear_max;
private TextInputEditText input_fname;
private List<LinearLayout> layout_list;
private AlertDialog.Builder alertdialog;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_setting);
    alertdialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    layout_list = new ArrayList<LinearLayout>();
    toolbar = (android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.activity_setting_toolbar);
    toolbar.setCollapsible(true);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Setting");
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDefaultDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    input_fname = (TextInputEditText) findViewById(R.id.setting_edittext_fname);
    input_fname.setText("test");
    layout_list.add(linear_fname = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.setting_layout_fname));
    /*layout_list.add(linear_lname = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.setting_layout_lname));
    layout_list.add(linear_birthdate = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.setting_layout_birthdate));
    layout_list.add(linear_gender = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.setting_layout_gender));
    layout_list.add(linear_tel = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.setting_layout_tel));
    layout_list.add(linear_carefname = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.setting_layout_caretaker_fname));
    layout_list.add(linear_carelname = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.setting_layout_caretaker_lname));
    layout_list.add(linear_careemail = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.setting_layout_caretaker_email));
    layout_list.add(linear_caretel = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.setting_layout_caretaker_tel));
    layout_list.add(linear_range = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.setting_layout_glucose_range));
    layout_list.add(linear_min = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.setting_textLayout_minglucose));
    layout_list.add(linear_max = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.setting_textLayout_maxglucose));*/

    for(LinearLayout linearLayout : layout_list){
        linearLayout.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
}

public void onClick(View v){
    if(v.getId() == R.id.setting_layout_fname){
        final EditText edittext = new EditText(getApplicationContext());
        alertdialog.setTitle("First Name");
        alertdialog.setMessage("Enter your firstname: ");
        alertdialog.setView(edittext);
        alertdialog.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                final String fname = edittext.getText().toString();
                Toast.makeText(setting.this, fname, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                setting.this.input_fname.setText( fname,  TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);
            }
        });
        alertdialog.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
            }
        });
        alertdialog.create().show();
    }
}
```

don't know what happen with my code, Toast always show same value as I put it but it not show in edittext of mainActivity.

Comment: `setting.this` what is this ? `setting` is a `Activity` instance? that contain `input_fname` ?

Comment: Sorry for late reply. Before I'm edit my code, I set onClick event by using anonymous inner class. So I use setting.this from anonymous inner class with onClick method to refer to outter class.

Comment: .. and where is the `editText` in which you want to set the value?

Comment: Sorry again, editText that I want to set is "input_fname" and I get value that use to set from "edittext" in alertdialog

Answer (score 0):

code have 2 edittext, the 1st is editText in alertdialog that created programmatically, and the 2nd is editText that create in xml file.

All I want to do is setText to editText in xml with value from editText in alertdialog. I can got the value from edittext in alertdialog but cannot setText to editText in xml file.

```
package com.example.yggdrasil.realapplication;

import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class setting extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

private android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar toolbar;
private LinearLayout linear_fname, linear_lname, linear_birthdate, linear_gender, linear_tel,
        linear_carefname, linear_carelname, linear_careemail, linear_caretel, linear_range,
        linear_min, linear_max;
private TextInputEditText input_fname;
private List<LinearLayout> layout_list;
private AlertDialog.Builder alertdialog;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_setting);
    alertdialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    layout_list = new ArrayList<LinearLayout>();
    toolbar = (android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.activity_setting_toolbar);
    toolbar.setCollapsible(true);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Setting");
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDefaultDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    input_fname = (TextInputEditText) findViewById(R.id.setting_edittext_fname);
    input_fname.setText("test");
    layout_list.add(linear_fname = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.setting_layout_fname));

    for(LinearLayout linearLayout : layout_list){
        linearLayout.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
}

public void onClick(View v){
    if(v.getId() == R.id.setting_layout_fname){
        final EditText edittext = new EditText(getApplicationContext());
        alertdialog.setTitle("First Name");
        alertdialog.setMessage("Enter your firstname: ");
        alertdialog.setView(edittext);
        alertdialog.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                final String fname = edittext.getText().toString();
                Toast.makeText(setting.this, fname, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                setting.this.input_fname.setText( fname,  TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);
            }
        });
        alertdialog.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
            }
        });
        alertdialog.create().show();

    }
}
```

layout code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/activity_setting_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:divider="?android:dividerHorizontal"
        android:showDividers="middle"
        android:padding="10dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/setting_layout_fname"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="100"
            android:clickable="true">

            <TextView
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="25"
                android:clickable="false"
                android:text="Firstname"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" />


            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/setting_textLayout_fname"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:layout_weight="75"
                android:clickable="false">

                <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                    android:id="@+id/setting_edittext_fname"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:clickable="false"/>
            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: So sorry, my code has 2 editText, the first one  is in alert dialog that I create programmatically , and the second one is the EditText in xml file that I want to set text with a text from EditText in alert dialog.

Comment: post your whole code and edit your   your question in detail

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm... I figure something. When I create new xml class withly slight same element with the old one, It perfectly work either with editText or textView. So I think I did some mistake and overlook it. So I guess that I should answer my own question.